# click function in loop not sending all variables

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I've spent a lot of time over the past 2 days trying to find the solution to this but my inexperience has got in the way.

I'm developing an image map resource. A user opens a modal window that contains a dynamic url.
As you can see from my code, I've tested an alert which throws up different ids (correct result) but the same doesn't apply to the url window. I'm only getting one url variable, not 2 as I have with the alert popup.

I'm sure it's a structural thing but any pointers would be appreciated.

```
function tree(tree_id, mappos) {
    this.tree_id = tree_id;
    this.mappos = mappos;
}

var mytreelist = [];
mytreelist[0] = new tree(18, "708,290,736,319"),
mytreelist[1] = new tree(272, "134,143,163,172");

for (i = 0; i < mytreelist.length; i++) {

    document.write("<div id = \"" + mytreelist[i].tree_id + "\" > <area class = \"maplink\"     
    shape= \"rect\" coords=\"" + mytreelist[i].mappos + "\" data-role=\"button\" href=\"#\" 
    id=\"" + mytreelist[i].tree_id + "\"/></div>");

    treeid = this.mytreelist[i].tree_id;

    $("#" + treeid).click(function() {
        var win = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
        thing = this.id;
        alert("tree number " + thing);
        win.center();
        win.open();
    });
 }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#window").kendoWindow({
            height: "400px",
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            title: "Centered Window",
            modal: true,
            visible: false,
            width: "600px",
            content: "check.php?tree_id=" + treeid,
            title: "Async Window Content"
        });
    });
```

OK. trying to simplify the idea here and use an enclosure function. I still have the same issue. I can access the array element id but not its value.

```
var mytreelist = ['elm', 'oak', 'pine'];

function create() {
    for (var i = 0; i < mytreelist.length; i++) {
    mytreelist[i] = function(tree) {
    var newtree = this.mytreelist.value; //this is not correct?
    return function() {

    alert("tree = " + newtree);

      };
  }(i);
 }
}

function run() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  mytreelist[i]();
  }
}

create();
run();
```

Comment: Your div and area has one id. You need to change some of them.

Comment: You placed `$(document).ready(function() { $("#window").kendoWindow({ ...` inside the `for loop`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I've made these changes but still not getting different url parameters. Interesting that the only url output is for the second iteration of the loop - `mytreelist[1]` - so the url becomes `check.php?tree_id="272"`

Comment: I've done some more research and think I need to use a closure on my treeid variable. I'm having trouble writing this.